# Hide div when scroll down only on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = function() {
    var t = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    var left_bar = document.getElementById("left_bar");
    if (t >= 80 && $('wrapper').width() <= 478 ) {
        left_bar.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        left_bar.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

I am trying to hide a div when user scroll down only on mobile device. i don't want hide it on pc or tablet.

but i can't do it right..hope for help thanks

Comment: I'm curious to why you are mixing `jQuery` with pure `javascript` for this? If you have the `jQuery` library loading in why not make use of it?

Comment: detect if the device is mobile. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: There are numerous javascript libraries for detecting mobile browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

`wrapper` isn't a valid HTML tag. Therefore, just change `$('wrapper')` to `$('.wrapper')` and give a class `wrapper` to body element.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    var t = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    var left_bar = document.getElementById("left_bar");
    if (t >= 80 && $('.wrapper').width() <= 478 ) {
        left_bar.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        left_bar.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#left_bar {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body class='wrapper'>
  <div id='left_bar'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why set a `class` name for the body tag? Why not an `ID` or simply target `$('body')`?

Comment: Yes, you can also do that. I just showed you an example